# Android studio Signature Algorithm mismatch

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

When I create a projetct in android studio, it gives me at the beginning this error :

> Gradle 'MyApplication12' project refresh failed Error:Signature
>   algorithm mismatch

I don't know what's the problem

Comment: You need to give more information. Is the project actually created? What version of Android Studio?

Comment: Yes it's actually created, my android studio version is 1.0.1 my JRE 1.8, and all my new project did not working and give me the error like mentionned at the topic

Comment: Have you tried using one of the samples? Have you tried creating form scratch via build.gradle?

Comment: how to do that ? can you explain more and thank's

Comment: File -> Import. I am just saying to import an existing project.

Comment: existing project work correctly but the newer project gives me problems

Comment: It maybe your Android Studio install. I can't find any information on this error. An easy work around would be to copy an existing project, then import it and edit it.

Comment: Please leave this question open. I hope you can get an answer. I have not heard of this error before. Can you possible post a photo?

Comment: yes me too I had never hear like this error, ok it's still open thank's

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this problem will be fixed by doing the below step.

Go to

```
File->Setting->Gradle->Gradle Vm Option
```

, Now put this value `-Xmx256m` in the box, and hit the `Apply` `button`.

Comment: Seems like a weird reason for causing a cryptographic error instead of an usual memory-related exception. Why is the lack if memory causing this kind of error?