# Error Signature algorithm mismatch

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I create a project in android studio, it gives me at the beginning this error :

> Error:Signature algorithm mismatch

I don't know what's the problem

Comment: Just for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592523/android-studio-signature-algorithm-mismatch (unanswered)

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution! This problem will be fixed by doing the below step.

Go to

```
File->Setting->Gradle->Gradle Vm Option
```

Now put this value `-Xmx256m` in the box, and hit the `Apply` button.